# Is there a way to download an object from S3 bucket to a file destination using AWS SDK for .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to find a way to download objects from a S3 bucket to a file destination using AWS SDK for .NET.

I can get a list of the objects and delete the objects, but I don't see anywhere that you can download an object. Please help.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingNetSDK.html

Comment: Where would you put your folder destination to download? I think this would just get a list of objects. Or maybe I'm missing something. @DanielA.White

Answer (score 3):

When you get an object, the S3 C# API has a helper method for saving the response stream directly to a file. You could also open a file stream and write the response stream to the file manually if you needed more control over it.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_S3_Model_GetObjectResponse.htm

```
var client = new AmazonS3Client("yourAccessId", "yourSecretKey");


using (var obj = client.GetObject("yourBucket", "yourObject"))
{
  obj.WriteResponseStreamToFile("some/file/path.ext");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the S3 TransferUtility to download a file directly without having to use a stream object. For example:

```
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Transfer;

// Replace the following variables with the appropriate
// values for the files for the files you want to download.
var bucketName = "s3photos";
var s3Key = "mypicture.jpg";
var filePath = "downloadpath" + "\\" + s3Key;

var client = new AmazonS3Client();
var transferUtil = new TransferUtility(client);

await transferUtility.DownloadAsync(new TransferUtilityDownloadRequest
{
    BucketName = bucketName,
    Key = s3Key,
    FilePath = filePath,
});

// Check to see if the file was downloaded.
if (File.Exists(filePath))
{
    Console.WriteLine("File successfully downloaded.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"File could not be downloaded. Make sure {s3Key}");
    Console.WriteLine($"exists in the bucket, {bucketName}.");
}
```